# count by all variables / count distinct with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have this `data.frame` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:3],1:3),y=rep(letters[1:3],1:3))
#   x y
# 1 a a
# 2 b b
# 3 b b
# 4 c c
# 5 c c
# 6 c c
```

I can group and count easily by mentioning the names :

```
df1 %>%
  count(x,y)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#        x      y     n
#   <fctr> <fctr> <int>
# 1      a      a     1
# 2      b      b     2
# 3      c      c     3
```

How do I do to group by everything without mentioning individual column names, in the most compact /readable way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can pass the input itself to the `...` argument and splice it with `!!!` :

```
df1 %>% count(., !!!.) 
#>   x y n
#> 1 a a 1
#> 2 b b 2
#> 3 c c 3
```

*Note : see edit history to make sense of some comments*

With base we could do : `aggregate(setNames(df1[1],"n"), df1, length)`

Comment: you can also use `group_by_all() %>% tally() `

Comment: regarding "readable" in the OP: section 4.3 of the [tidyverse style guide](http://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html) advises against omitting parentheses from functions in a pipe: `magrittr allows you to omit '()' on functions that don’t have arguments. Avoid this.`

Comment: Not much use in giving perspective advice if you don't offer any justification. Adding `()` takes more effort and looks worse, so the only possible justification I see is making the code more understandable. But the right side of `%>%` has to be a function anyway, so I'm not sure what confusion that would be preventing.

Comment: I've read it in the past and pondered it, but to my tastes the least ink the better, especially about parentheses. The only problem to me is that when using the `::` notation parentheses are mandatory, which brings inconsistencies in my code. I can't thing of another disadvantage.

Comment: @Ryan, *here's the justification I was implying, but perhaps should have spelled out*: The developers of these packages also wrote the majority of the style guide, which I assume is based on their experience with people using/mis-using their functions.  This is their advice how to make the code more consistent & readable. I tend to trust their collective experience and follow their advice in most scenarios.  I think their opinion is worth bringing to the OP's attention when he asked for opinions about "the most readable way".

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, makes sense about less ink.  I do tend to favor longer variable & fx names than most people, and I almost always qualify functions that aren't in `base` with their containing package.

Comment: I also often align the pipes on the right side to leave the left side as naked as possible (and move these 3 ugly characters "out of sight") and to reenforce the "block look" of the pipe chain. I don't think I've seen anyone else do it though.

Comment: Cool  --makes sense why you'd favor dropping redundant parentheses.  Kinda like the formatting of section 1 [of this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949896/r-convert-values-into-pipe-delimited-format/51013678#51013678), but with `%>%` replacing the `=`?  I haven't seen that style, but I appreciate some of its advantages.

Comment: Yes, I also align equal signs a lot, sometimes even parentheses, and in the rare cases where I use a `%T>%` pipe I tend to leave them on the same line, which would otherwise be disgraceful, like in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167043/print-data-frame-dimensions-at-each-step-of-filtering/48264845#48264845

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper There must have been a breaking change with the bang operators at some point, as this does not work in dplyr 1.0.7

Comment: Good catch, the breaking change is not in the bang operators but in magrittr which doesn't insert an implicit dot if an argument is `!!!.` , see updated answer.

Comment: `count()`has changed too in that it doesn't output a tibble anymore if fed a regular data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the (now superceded) group_by_all()?

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:3],1:3),y=rep(letters[1:3],1:3))
df1 %>% group_by_all() %>% count
df1 %>% group_by(across()) %>% count()
df1 %>% count(across()) # don't know why this returns a data.frame and not tibble
```

See the [colwise vignette "other verbs" section](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html#other-verbs) for explanation... though honestly I get turned around myself sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

For those who wouldn't get the voodoo you are using in the accepted answer, if you don't *need* to use `dplyr`, you can do it with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df1)
df1[, .N, names(df1)]
#    x y N
# 1: a a 1
# 2: b b 2
# 3: c c 3
```